# Typed dataset for populating custom objects ?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm about to develop database server app; I have decided not to use typed dataset/dataset, **except** in the DAL, (so I'm not asking the question whether to use dataset or custom objects).

Populating my custom objects with data requires an interaction with DataSet in the DAL.

I have seen a [reasonable way](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CustomBindableObject.aspx) of using typed dataset for this purpose. Is typed dataset is the right choice in this scenario ?

Comment: Re discussion on my (deleted) answer; I have re-phrased the question to try to make this clearer.

Comment: i need clear information abt this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you dont need types datasets if you are populating your own objects, just use a basic reader to get the data (implementing any checks for nulls etc as your architecture requires)

Comment: no dataset at all ? what about loading/saving hierarchical from/to objects ? is'nt it preferable operation to do with a dataset (typed/untyped) ?

Comment: YOu dont need types datasets that include additional data, since you;re just interested in getting the vales and populating your own objects, use whatever the most light-weight data option is.